# How to get android device Unique ID in a Game Guardian Lua script

Tags: android, lua

I'm writing a script in lua, and want to secure it with their device id , so it cannt be passed on. Is there a secure way to get their unique device id?

Comment: Are you using Corona?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff no, it is a game guardian script